# Calculate UIBezierPath Curved Control Point

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uibezierpath

I'm struggling to understand how to achieve the following component:

[image]

[image]

**Theory:**

I've managed to create 4 draggable UIView'. When one of the UIView change position I'm creating UIBezierPath from connecting each UIView center, to a box shape and displaying it using CAShapeLayer.
I can't understand how to calculate the "addQuadCurve" control point to achieve the curved lines in the illustration.

Current Code:

```
func updateLines() {
 let path = UIBezierPath()
 path.move(to: v.center)
 path.addLine(to: v2.center)
 path.addLine(to: v4.center)
 path.addLine(to: v3.center)
 path.close()
 line.path = path.cgPath
 line.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
 line.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
}
```

**Any help or advice for the right direction will be highly appreciated.
Best regards,
Roi**

Comment: You have *at least* two technical issues to deal with. (1) The simpler one is to learn how to draw a *4 sided polygon* or *quadrilateral* on a "canvas" based on 4 points. Note that this *is not* with parallel sides or a rectangular shape, but *is* with straight lines for each side - and you'll need to include "rules" in your code to make sure the "sides" do not intersect. But that's the *easy* part. (2) Next, you'll need to define "rules" on drawing the bezier path on a curve... I notice that your example has *no* rhyme or reason on the points on the curves. Good luck.

Comment: Hey @dfd , thank you for replying. Actually I have already solved issue (1). I have a working 4 draggable UIViews which create a "box" using bezier path, displayed by CAShapeLayer. My issue now is with the "control point", how do I calculate slightly roundish control point for each line (lines connect from each UIView center). Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that this shape consists of four quadratic or cubic splines where its supporting points are computed relative to the corner points. How does your shape look like, if the corner points are the corners of a rectangle?

Comment: @clemens It looks like a rectangle, flat, with no curves. When I move one of the corners after setting the shape to rectangle. I see the curve starting very close the the corner, no in the middle. I'll add sample at the question

Comment: @clemens Added more illustrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a connected set of cubic Bezier curves where the beginning and end are the same point. If you watch the animation, it looks like as you drag different points, the point that's the beginning/end of the curve gets changed.

Watch carefully and you'll see that 3 of the 4 corners are smooth curves, and one has a "kink" in it. The kinked corner seems to be a point other than the one that's being moved. That's probably the begin/end point.

Comment: Hey Duncan, Thank you for replying. Unfortunately I couldn't understand how to translate your answer into code. Any chance you can elaborate a little more or provide sample code? Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually I think it might be simpler. It looks like it might be 2 different pairs of linked quadratic or cubic bezier curves where each has a starting point on the top left and the end-point is the bottom right. I'm guessing that one curve is made up of 2 quadratic Bezier curves: The first has one endpoint at the top left corner and the 2nd endpoint at the top right; the 2nd has and points at top right and bottom right. I don't know how the intermediate control points are derived.